# How to customize margin in only one page?

Tags: margins, templates

In the latex template below, I need to reduce the right and left margins **ONLY** on the title page:

**Latex template:** [University of Oxford Mathematical Institute PhD Thesis Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-oxford-mathematical-institute-phd-thesis-template/xzvzjnxbmftm)

**NOTE: the approach proposed by @John Smith changes margins for in other pages as well ...**

To clarify the question, please refer to the attached image:

**Note:** My title is much longer than this one, occupying multiple lines and causing limited space for other information.

[image]

The class file, named `ociamthesis.cls`, is as follows:

```
%
% ociamthesis v2.2
% By Keith A. Gillow <gillow@maths.ox.ac.uk>
% Version 1.0 released 26/11/1997
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{ociamthesis}[2010/11/22 v2.2 OCIAM thesis class]
%-------------------------- initial code -----------------------
\def\logoversion{squarelogo}
\DeclareOption{beltcrest}{\def\logoversion{beltcrest}}
\DeclareOption{shieldcrest}{\def\logoversion{shieldcrest}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}
% As an alternative to the above could use next line for twosided output
%\LoadClass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\RequirePackage{graphicx} % needed for latest frontpage logo
\RequirePackage{ifthen}   % needed for option parsing for logo

\raggedbottom

%define the default submitted text
\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{A thesis submitted for the degree of}}

%
% DECLARATIONS
%
% These macros are used to declare arguments needed for the
% construction of the title page and other preamble.

% The year and term the thesis is submitted 
\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}
% The full (unabbreviated) name of the degree
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
% The name of your Oxford college (e.g. Christ Church, Pembroke)
\def\college#1{\gdef\@college{#1}}


%
% Setup choosen crest/logo
%

\ifthenelse{\equal{\logoversion}{shieldcrest}}%
{
% Traditional Oxford shield crest
%Using latex metafont (Mathematical Institute system)
\font\crestfont=oxcrest40 scaled\magstep3
\def\logo{{\crestfont \char1}}
%For comlab system replace 1st line above with
%\font\crestfont=crest scaled\magstep3
}{}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\logoversion}{beltcrest}}%
{
% Newer Oxford Belt crest
%Using latex metafont (Mathematical Institute system)
\font\beltcrestfont=oxbeltcrest
\def\logo{{\beltcrestfont \char0}}
%For comlab system replace 1st line above with
%\font\beltcrestfont=newcrest
}{}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\logoversion}{squarelogo}}%
{
% Latest Logo, Square version (the default!)
% you need an oxlogo.eps or oxlogo.pdf file as appropriate
\def\logo{{\includegraphics[width=32mm]{oxlogo}}}
}{}

%
% Define text area of page and margin offsets
%
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.33in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.08in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.0in}

%
% Environments
%

% This macro define an environment for front matter that is always 
% single column even in a double-column document.

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse
       \if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
       \fi}%
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn
       \else\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\fi}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
    { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
{\large \vspace*{40mm} {\logo \par} \vspace*{25mm}}
    {{\Large \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@college} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {University of Oxford \par}
\vspace*{25mm}
    {{\submittedtext} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}
  \null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}}

% DEDICATION
%
% The dedication environment makes sure the dedication gets its
% own page and is set out in verse format.

\newenvironment{dedication}
{\begin{alwayssingle}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\LARGE }
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
  \begin{verse}\begin{center}}
{\end{center}\end{verse}\end{alwayssingle}}


% ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%
% The acknowledgements environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgements
% themselves appear in a quote environment, i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and
% on its own page.

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

% The acknowledgementslong environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgement itself 
% does not appears in a quote environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{acknowledgementslong}
{\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

% STATEMENT OF ORIGINALITY (AS SUGGESTED BY GSW)
%
% The originality environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Statement of originality" label at the top of the page. The statement 
% of originality itself appears in a quote environment, i.e. tabbed in at 
% both sides, and on its own page.

\newenvironment{originality}
{\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Statement of Originality}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

% The originalitylong environment puts a large, bold, centered 
% "Statement of originality" label at the top of the page. The statement 
% of originality itself does not appears in a quote environment so you can 
% get more in.

\newenvironment{originalitylong}
{\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Statement of Originality}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}


%ABSTRACT
%
%The abstract environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself appears in a quote environment,
%i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and on its own page.

\renewenvironment{abstract} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractlong environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself does not appears in a quote
%environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{abstractlong} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractseparate environment is for running of a page with the abstract
%on including title and author etc as required to be handed in separately

\newenvironment{abstractseparate} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1in}
 \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1ex} \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@college} \par}
    {University of Oxford \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\it \submittedtext} \par}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

%ROMANPAGES
%
% The romanpages environment set the page numbering to lowercase roman one
% for the contents and figures lists. It also resets
% page-numbering for the remainder of the dissertation (arabic, starting at 1).

\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\cleardoublepage\setcounter{page}{1}\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\cleardoublepage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}
```

Comment: why change the margins, just use center and force a linebreak after `Two` with `\\ `

Comment: @David Carlisle , My title is much longer than this one, occupying multiple lines and causing limited space for other information.

Comment: Try `\centering\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{4cm} ... \end{minipage}` or whatever width you want.

Comment: @John Kormylo, Where exactly should I put the command of `minipage` ?

Comment: If you only want to change them for the title, you could use `changepage`'s `adjustwidth`?

Comment: @cfr , Could you explain in detail how to use `changepage` as an Answer? Thanks

Comment: Depends, but probably right after `\titlepage` and before `\maketitle`.

Comment: Can you post an example I can compile?

Comment: @cfr , The Latex template including all required file is found in the following link : [University of Oxford Mathematical Institute PhD Thesis Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-oxford-mathematical-institute-phd-thesis-template/xzvzjnxbmftm)

Answer (score 1):

First add this in the .cls file:

```
\RequirePackage{geometry}
```

Then replace the `\maketitle` command in the .cls file with this:
`\newgeometry{left=1in, right=1in}` sets the left and right margins to 1 inch(you can change), and `\restoregeometry` reverts to the original layout settings.

```
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \newgeometry{left=1in, right=1in} % Adjust margins for the title page
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \null\vfill
    \begin{center}
        { \Huge {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
        {\large \vspace*{40mm} {\logo \par} \vspace*{25mm}}
        {{\Large \@author} \par}
        {\large \vspace*{1ex}
        {{\@college} \par}
        \vspace*{1ex}
        {University of Oxford \par}
        \vspace*{25mm}
        {{\submittedtext} \par}
        \vspace*{1ex}
        {\it {\@degree} \par}
        \vspace*{2ex}
        {\@degreedate}}
    \end{center}
    \null\vfill
    \restoregeometry % Restore the original margins for the rest of the document
\end{alwayssingle}}
```

Old title page output:
[image]
New title page output:
[image]

Comment: Note: Loading `geometry` (without option `pass`) already changes the margins.

Comment: @John Smith , Your approach changes margins for in other pages as well ...

Comment: If `\RequirePackage{geometry}` is removed, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with `titlepage` enviroment and `geometry` package commands

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}  % default square logo 
%\documentclass[12pt,beltcrest]{ociamthesis} % use old belt crest logo
%\documentclass[12pt,shieldcrest]{ociamthesis} % use older shield crest logo

%load any additional packages
\usepackage{amssymb}

%input macros (i.e. write your own macros file called mymacros.tex 
%and uncomment the next line)
%\include{mymacros}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1.5in,left=1.5in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry



%end the preamble and start the document
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=2.5in,left=2.5in}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{Codimension-Two\\[1ex]     %your thesis title,
        Free Boundary Problems}   %note \\[1ex] is a line break in the title

\author{Keith Gillow}             %your name
\college{St Catherine's College}  %your college

%\renewcommand{\submittedtext}{change the default text here if needed}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}     %the degree
\degreedate{Trinity 1998}         %the degree date
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}


\restoregeometry

%this baselineskip gives sufficient line spacing for an examiner to easily
%markup the thesis with comments
\baselineskip=18pt plus1pt

%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


                  % create a title page from the preamble info
\include{dedication}        % include a dedication.tex file
\include{acknowlegements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file
\include{abstract}          % include the abstract

\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents
\listoffigures              % generate and include a list of figures
\end{romanpages}            % end roman page numbering

%now include the files of latex for each of the chapters etc
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{conclusions}

%now enable appendix numbering format and include any appendices
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}

%next line adds the Bibliography to the contents page
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{refs}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib
\bibliographystyle{plain}  %use the plain bibliography style

\end{document}
```